# multi-color cross fade in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've searched (really) but cannot find how to do this exactly... I'd like to cross fade multiple colors (transition the gradient) much like I am doing here (but it simply shows the three colors).  I'd like to end up with a blend of the two colors as it transitions.

This is where I am now, with no idea on how to implement a cross fade:

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var active = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = colors[active % colors.length];
    active++;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: yep, fixed the typo!  I can use the ```document.body.style.backgroundColor``` but I am going to change this later to another object.  this is just for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the [`transition` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

```js
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var active = 0;
document.body.style.transition = 'background-color 5000ms';
setInterval(function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[active % colors.length];
  active++;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: outstanding!  just too darned simple! THANKS!